# Strip .html for a url redirect

Tags: .net, url, web-config, redirect

I am doing a redirect from an old site to a new site which uses friendly urls.

the url going in is example.com/news-events/some-news-story.html which redirects to anotherdomain.com/news/some-news-story

now the rule ive built so far does everything except strip the .html from the end so its redirecting to anotherdomain.com/news/some-news-story.html.

This should be simple but im drawing a blank.

heres the rule:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect news posts" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^news-events/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.anotherdomain.com/news/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

any help/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this by running this rule on the URL also

```
<rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\." negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
    </rule>
```

Which came from [this site](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx)